# Project Euler - multiples of numbers

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I'm trying to learn functional programming and Scala, following through Project Euler problems.

I'm solving get the sum of multiples x & y in a list. So for a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` get multiples of 3, 5 returns 3, 5, 6 and 9, the sum being 23.

1. I'm accepting two parameters `list` and `multiples`
2. Mapping multiples to list of functions, that test if input is a multiple
3. Filtering anything that returns true in the mapped multiples list

```
  def multiplesOf(list: List[Int], multiples: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    def filterMultipleOf(x: Int) : Int => Boolean = (y: Int) => {
      y % x == 0
    }
    val multiplesFilter = multiples.map(filterMultipleOf(_))
    list.filter( int => multiplesFilter.exists(mOf => mOf(int)))
  }

scala> multiplesOf(List.range(1,10), List(3,5)).sum
res: Int = 23
```

**My main question: Is this the Scale/FP way?**

Is defining `filterMultipleOf` inside my function still pure? Is there a better way to express this in Scala or FP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit more concise (and perhaps more idiomatic).

```
def multiplesOf(list: List[Int], multiples: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val filt: Int => Boolean = multiples.foldLeft { _: Int => false } {
    case (f, n) => x => f(x) || x%n == 0
  }
  list.filter(filt)
}
```

And don't name variables the same as a type (`int` --> `Int`). It's visually confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your function is still pure. A pure function has only two requirements:

1. The return value will always be the same given the same arguments.
2. Evaluation will produce no side effects.

Since `filterMultipleOf` only uses integers, the second is obviously met, no mutation is possible. The first requirement is also met. Calling `filterMultipleOf(1)` creates a function which is distinct from the function created by calling `filterMultipleOf(2)`. See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/235175/257523) on software engineering for an alternative explanation.

Is there a better way to express this function? Yes.

1. Just because your functions are short doesn't mean stop thinking about names. `x` and `y` are about as vague as you can get. Renaming `x` to `factor` and `y` to `multiple` immediately makes the function clearer. Also, `multiplesOf` takes a list of `factors`, not a list of `multiples`.

   Naming variables after their type is generally a bad idea. `int` should be called `multiple`. `list` is a bit more difficult. In this case I would leave it as is since I can't quickly come up with a better name (`numbers` really doesn't help much).
2. You can pass functions around without specifying a single partial. Do `multiples.map(filterMultipleOf)` instead of `multiples.map(filterMultipleOf(_))`
3. I don't see the need for `filterMultipleOf`, you can just use an anonymous function without losing any meaning. `factors.map(factor => (multiple: Int) => multiple % factor == 0)`
4. Choosing to create a function for each factor makes your function logic take more space since you now have to call each function. I believe it is more clear to create a helper function that checks all factors:

   ```scala
   def multiplesOf(list: List[Int], factors: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
     val isMultiple = (multiple: Int) => factors.exists(factor => multiple % factor == 0)
     list.filter(isMultiple)
   }
   ```

   You could further reduce this function by providing `isMultiple` as a lambda, but this is really dependent on your style. I'd go for it in this case.

   ```scala
   def multiplesOf(list: List[Int], factors: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
     list.filter(multiple => factors.exists(factor => multiple % factor == 0))
   }
   ```
5. It might be worth questioning the public API for this function. As it stands, it is only useful for lists of integers. What happens if you have a list of another type - say, `Person` and you want all people whose age is a multiple of 3 or 5? Right now, you can't use this function.

   If the function was slightly modified to tell if a single integer is a multiple of some factor, then you can use the function.

   ```scala
   val multipleOf = (multiple: Int, factors: List[Int]) =>
     factors.exists(factor => multiple % factor == 0)

   class Person(var name: String, var age: Int) {
     override def toString: String = s"$name is $age"
   }

   val people = List(
     new Person("Adam", 25),
     new Person("Bob", 7),
     new Person("Cate", 12),
     new Person("Dave", 20),
     new Person("Edward", 8)
   )

   people
     .filter(person => multipleOf(person.age, List(3, 5)))
     .foreach(println)
   ```

   With this change, your original function can be trivially defined:

   ```scala
   val multipleOf = (multiple: Int, factors: List[Int]) =>
     factors.exists(factor => multiple % factor == 0)

   val multiplesOf = (list: List[Int], factors: List[Int]) =>
     list.filter(multipleOf(_, factors))
   ```